Why does my plot_model() look like this? (Tensorflow, Keras)
I made a very simple model, so I could practise using the plot_model() function, but for some reason my plot model looks like this? enter image description here
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

'''model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.mae,
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
              metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=100, verbose=0)
model.summary'''
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model=model,to_file='model3.png',show_shapes=True)


compared to:
enter image description here
The other person's code: enter image description here

dont use images to describe the code, provide the code

sorry for some reason its not allowing me to

I believe that your error is coming from your definition of "Dense": would you be able to show how to you imported that layer definition?
The below code (which is the same as your initial code, but with the use of tf.keras.layers.Dense as opposed to just Dense) seems to work as expected.
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=(1,)))

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model=model, show_shapes=True)


alright, ill add the imports to the original message

for some reason, even using that it doesnt work - maybe its a visual studio thing?

It is unprobable that its a visual studio code thing, but if it is, try using python IDE or jupyter notebook, what version of tensorflow are you using?
